# How to restrict a child table's search field value on pre-selected parent field value using jQuery+Ajax

Tags: django, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete search for a model field based on a related model's FK field. For instance, names of a child model's values to be restricted on the preselected value of the key field of parent model (akin to **Country > City** scenario).

### **My question is:**

How do I pass the Country model's primary key (`id`) (selected in the country autocomplete field) to the **CitySearch** view (variable `country_search_id`) which I could then  use in the QuerySet (in the first `.filter`)? The **country id** value is stored in a form field on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not optimal at all, but might work:

You could store the country_id captured by the onChange's Ajax function on a hidden text input, then retrieve it on your City Search's view.